# About validity of EMC & Safety Test Reports without NABL & ILAC-MRA

Tags: certification, compliance

Can anyone provide the info regarding that the EMC & Safety test reports without NABL & ILAC-MRA are valid or not?

Is it mandatory to have both the marks for CE & UKCA self declaration?

Comment: For what kind of product? To b be sold in what jurisdiction?

Comment: For the lab devices like Centrifuge, stirrer, dry bath, shakers etc. Also the standards applicable for testing are EN/IEC 61326-1, EN/IEC 61010-1, EN/IEC 61010-2-020, EN/IEC 61010-2-051. To sell the products in Europe & GB.